# NodeJS response is not parsed by express or bodyparser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shop');
// app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
// app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json())


router.get('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {

    res.send('<form action="/product" method="POST"><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>')
})
```

the response isn't parsed .. I tried 1k things .. Nothing works... i still receive undefined
i tried both variants `**app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})); and  app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));  + app.use(bodyParser.json()) and  app.use(express.json());**` 
What's to do ? thank you in advance

Comment: Can you share the route that handles `/product`?

Comment: Please post an example that reproduces the problem.  Remember that body parser etc. are for the `request` not the response, and I don't see anything in your example using the request body?

Answer (score 0):

you should have `app.get` and not `router.get`
See [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)